# Filter by text input, how can I add RegEx? - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, input, css-selectors, mixitup

I'm using Mixitup.js with vanilla Javascript. [Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elijah92/svo5rcx0/13/).

When you type in "blue", "green", or "pink" it only shows elements with that class name.

What I want is to filter the results with ReGex, for example by using: `new RegExp('^|\\s','gi')`. However, I have no idea how to write this properly, nor implement it into the code.

Right now, when you type in "reen", it will still show results for "green". I don't want this. I only want results that match from the beginning of the word (hence `^|`).

I've kept the comments in the script from the dev's demo, hopefully that helps. [Full demo is here](https://demos.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/filtering-by-text-input/)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you are using an attribute based selector to select elements where class begins with particular text. But in your example the elements have two classes "mix" and the color name

> class ="mix green"

Simply using **[class^=color class name**] will not work.

Try replacing

> mixer.filter('[class*="' + searchValue + '"]');

with

> mixer.filter('[class^="mix ' + searchValue + '"]');